# Elements in an array will not change c++

Tags: c++, arrays

```
   void Remove(int x)//x is the number that i want to remove
    {
        for(int i=0;i<CAPACITY;i++)//loop is to find the first case of x
        {
             if(x==data[i])//if x is in data 
             {
                  cout<<data[i]<<endl;//for debugging
                  data[i]==0; //change x to 0
                  cout<<data[i]<<endl;
             }
        }
     }
```

when i cout to see if it works the number that i wanted to delete is still there.
Here is the output before i run it when x=15:
12,15,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
I used cout to see if there was a problem with the condition however it runs if x is in the array. 
Here is the output after, even if x is in the array:
 
12,15,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

Comment: `data[i]==0; //change x to 0` no that is the comparison operator, remove one of the `=`

Comment: `==` means "check equality". `=` means "assign value". You want the latter.

Comment: Just was a careless mistake. Thanks for the help nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your If loop you use `comparison operator '=='` so put only one `=` which means you assign variable x to data array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in in the line `data[i]==0; //change x to 0`

**==** is an comparison operator. In order to assign a value use `=` instead. So:

`data[i] = 0`